# ABAP Workbench: How to identify all occurrences of a highlighted variable

Tags: abap

While in ABAP Workbench, I select a variable (as shown in the attachment).

I want the ABAP workbench to highlight me all occurrences of the selected variable in the ABAP code.

Is it possible?

[image: Identify all occurances of the selected variable in ABAP workbench]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F2 or double-click to navigate to the declaration, then use the where-used index (the yellow square with the three arrows pointing away from it).

Answer (score 1):

Besides @vwegert's answer you can also double click the declaration.

Hope it helps.